# touchend is not triggered

Tags: javascript, touch, dom-events

I have implemented touchevents which evoke the same function like my mouse events:

onclick -> the touchstart { do something }

mousemover -> touchmove { do something }

mouseup -> touchend { do something }

All works but `touchend` is not triggered.

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', start);
function start(e){ do something ; touchDefaults(e); }

document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', move );
function move(e){ do something ; touchDefaults(e); }

document.body.addEventListener('touchend', end );
function end(e){ do something ; touchDefaults(e); }

document.body.addEventListener('touchcancel', cancel );
function cancel(e){ touchDefaults(e); }

document.body.addEventListener('touchleave', leave );
function leave(e){ touchDefaults(e); }
```

Comment: Please post 'real' code here